# Generating a sphere and a plane (intersecting) in VR program?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to generate a demo showing the intersection of a plane and a sphere in a VR program. Here's an example of how the program works:

//Example Curve.bvr

// Parametric curve
helix=parametricCurve
helix.setMinMax=t,-10,10
helix.setEquation=x,(cos(t))
helix.setEquation=y,(sin(t))
helix.setEquation=z,(.3*t)
helix.setSegmentCount=70
helix.setWidth=0.2,0.2
helix.color=red
helix.spawn

This will demo a red helix. 
How would I generate a demo for an intersecting plane and sphere? I'm very confused - Any help would be appreciated.